# Hidden column in grid is not saved

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

When I have a form with the design properties: 
WorkflowEnabled = Yes 
WindowType = Listpage
a hidden column in the grid will not be saved. Also the order of the columns when you drag and drop them, will not be saved. (in ax2012 this is not a problem).

When there is no actionpane it works correctly.
But when I use an actionpane with the following situation:
WorkflowEnabled = Yes 
WindowType = Listpage
Actionpane
Grid

The columns order will not be saved.

When I place the actionpane after the grid, there is also no problem.

You can find the xpo here: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9bAnQbtmH99TVdKcFpqQXMteWc)

Comment: Thank you for your input, i'm sorry. I made a mistake. WindowType = ListPage. I think it is not a standard form. (newbie, so too be honest, i have no idea)

Comment: I tried to make an xpo and came up with the following situation: Adding an actionpane will make the order of the columns not being saved.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9bAnQbtmH99WElLYTVOVDdxTFk) Here is my xpo file.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9bAnQbtmH99TVdKcFpqQXMteWc) too hasty, i'm sorry.

Comment: Curious. Well, at least I can confirm that I can reproduce the issue and also that moving the ActionPane after the Grid changes the behavior. But I need a bit more time to figure out why, probably by comparing your form against some of the standard ListPage forms, e.g. CustTableListPage. Could take a few days till I find the time, but maybe in the meantime someone else wants to take a stab at it. You may also want to [edit] the link to the .xpo into your question.

Comment: @FH-Inway thank you for you time

Comment: @FH-Inway Did you get the chance to give it a second look. It seems nobody else has the time or knows the anwswer

Comment: Sorry, no. Maybe next week.